# Exit-intent Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I want to create an exit-intent modal using bootstrap. I found a JavaScript code online and now I want to connect it to Bootstrap modal.

The code I found from the internet:

```
function onMouseOut(event) {
  // If the mouse is near the top of the window, show the popup
  // Also, do NOT trigger when hovering or clicking on selects
  if (
    event.clientY < 50 &&
    event.relatedTarget == null &&
    event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'select') {
    // Remove this event listener
    document.removeEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);

    // Show the popup
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  }
}

document.addEventListener("mouseout", onMouseOut);
```

Bootstrap Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e){
  if( e.clientY < 0 ){
    if(Number(sessionStorage.exit_init) != 1){
        sessionStorage.exit_init = 1;
        $("#exampleModal").modal()
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Just replace 'exampleModal' with whatever you called the ID.

Source: https://github.com/bilalucar/exit-intent-popup